# Update GUI without hang

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have action list which is a ArrayList. Object Action contains 3 parameters(button, action, time_it_takes). So what i have to is get a action form ArrayList perform it and wait for a while and then next action and so on. I have tried but nothing is updating in view it just hang for sometime and nothing updated. I have tried runOnUiThread but it also gives me error. Actually, i think i have weak multithreading concepts. Here is what i am trying...

```
  public void replay()
{
     ArrayList<Action> actions = gui.getActionList();
    for(i =0; i<actions.size(); i++)
    {
        gui.Replay(actions.get(i));
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(actions.get(i).getTime()); // delay for the next task
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Help Please

Comment: where do you call `replay()`?

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater(..) ?>

Comment: @Raghunandan in activity class

Comment: Is this called inside a thread/runnable/asynctask?

Comment: @SteveBenett No i am calling it in main Thread

Answer (score 1):

From your comments you are calling `replay()` from your activity which runs on the ui thread

You are calling `sleep` on the ui thread which blocks the ui thread. You should not block the ui thread. Do not call `Thread.sleep(2000)` in the ui thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

You can use a Handler if you wish you execute something every few seconds.

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
m_handler = new Handler();   
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something every 1 second 
    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

  }
  };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

To cancel the run

```
m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
```

Comment: I have also tried asynctask but it gives me error some thing like.."u cant update view here it should update in a thread where it created"

Comment: if i use aysnctask then how to acheive delay/sleep because i have to delay next action base on the time it takes

Comment: u can sleep in `doInbackground` but cannot update/modifu ui from it

Comment: can you provide me the basic structure code using runOnUiThread() because i have tryed this in a way like create a thread and then i a loop for each action create thread runOnUiThread() but it gives error of indexoutofbound.

Comment: @umerk44 you can use a handler. what is that you want to do?

Comment: i have never use hadler but let see what handler can do for me

Comment: @umerk44 check the edit. if you want to execute soemthing every few seconds you can use a handler